# How to know table name when inserting into two tables then triggering an exception

Tags: python, mysql, sql

My Python script inserts some data into two tables, just like,

```
try:
    ...
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''insert into table_A values (%s,%s)''',(value_1,value_2))  
    cur.execute('''insert into table_B values (%s,%s,%s)''',(value_1,value_2,value_3))
    ...
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)
```

The script has a problem:
When an exception occurs (e.g.,'Error 1062: Duplicate entry') , it's hard to know 'inserting table_A' throws the exception or 'inserting table_B' throws the exception, is there a way to know the table name via MySQLdb.Error when inserting triggers an exception ?

Comment: You could put the `try/catch` block around each `cur.execute` instead of around the whole block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trace the query that caused the error, make use of global variables for defining the *query* statement. And when an exception is raised, you can use the same variable to debug it.

**Example**:

```
globalVar = ""
try:
    ...
    cur = conn.cursor()
    globalVar = "insert into table_A values ( %s, %s )"
    cur.execute( globalVar, ( value_1, value_2 ) )  
    print "Row inserted in table_A" /* debug */

    globalVar = "insert into table_B values ( %s, %s, %s )"
    cur.execute( globalVar, ( value_1, value_2, value_3 ) )
    print "Row inserted in table_B" /* debug */

    ...
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % ( e.args[0], e.args[1] )
    print "SQL Query: %s" % globalVar /* debug in exception block */
    sys.exit (1)
```

As you can see the SQL Query in the log trace, you can easily figure out where and what the error is and take an action.

Comment: and this is the difference between senior and junior programmers. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    ...
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''insert into table_A values (%s,%s)''',(value_1,value_2)) 
    print 'table a inserted' 
    cur.execute('''insert into table_B values (%s,%s,%s)''',(value_1,value_2,value_3))
    print 'table b inserted'
    ...
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)
```

any print is missing then insert command above it has the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to run it in separates try´s (based on Barmar comment)

```
try:
    ...
    cur = conn.cursor()
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error Conecting the Database %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)
try:
    cur.execute('''insert into table_A values (%s,%s)''',(value_1,value_2))  
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error in table A %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)
try:
    cur.execute('''insert into table_B values (%s,%s,%s)''',(value_1,value_2,value_3))
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error Conecting in table B %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)
...
```